# Hebrew characters in Python code on eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, unicode

I'm writing python code on eclipse and whenver I use hebrew characters I get the following syntax error:

SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xfa' in file ... on line 66, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

How do I declare unicode/utf-8 encoding?

I tried adding

-*- coding: Unicode -*-

or

-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

in the commented section in the beginnning of the py file. It didn't work.

I'm running eclipse with pydev, python 2.6 on windows 7.

Comment: What happens if you try different IDE / editor?

Comment: @Ondrej Don't really have anything else... was hoping there is a simple solution inside eclipse.

Comment: Please state your operating system and python version.

Comment: There is an option to define the file encoding - take a look at:
[http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) btw - it was easy... the error i got directed me to that link..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing and it was because I'd tried to do:

```
a='言語版の記事'
```

When I should have done:

```
a=u'言語版の記事'
```

I think it's python/pydev complaining when trying to parse the source, rather than eclipse as such.

Comment: Sounds right (haven't checked). Also possible: `a = unicode('בלה בלה', encoding='utf-8')`

Answer (score 3):

I tried it also and here is my conclusion:
You should add

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

at the very first line in your file.
And yes, I work with windows...

If I got it right, you are missing the **`#`**

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the encoding the editor is using to enter data matches the declared encoding in the file metadata.

[image: Eclipse file properties dialog]

This isn't something unique to Eclipse or Python; it applies to all character data formats and text editors.

---

Python has a number of options for dealing with string literals in both the `str` and `unicode` types via escape sequences. I believe there were changes to string literals between Python 2 and 3.

- [Python 2.7 string literals](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)
- [Python 3.2 string literals](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)

Comment: It says default (utf-8) inherited from container.

Answer (score 0):

"Unicode" is certainly wrong, and `\xfa` is not UTF-8. Figure out which [encoding](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) is actually being used and declare that instead.

Comment: Can't figure out the encoding... I'll keep trying.

Comment: What character is `\xfa` *supposed* to be?

Comment: whichever hebrew letter I'm using the syntax error is always \xd7

Comment: `\xd7` *is* UTF-8. Try that again.

Comment: same error.
By the way, i'm copying the hebrew letters from outside because eclipse doesn't let me write in hebrew (why is that?)